# How to get the path from content root in python?

Tags: python, directory

Suppose that I have a working directory called directory 1. This directory has an app.py file and a directory file called directory2. Inside directory2 I have a text file called example.txt.

Is there a way of finding the path of example.txt using a command in app.py, knowing only the name of the text file and that it exists inside some directory of my working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OS.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is what you are after.

**Demo**

```
import os

def find_file():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        if 'example.txt' in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, 'example.txt')
            print(f'file exists at {path}')
            return
    print('file does not exist')

find_file()
```

Comment: This shows that it exists. How do I find the relative path of this file?

Comment: Sure, root will provide the path to the directory the file is stored so you can join root with the filename. I have updated the code to reflect this. And if you want the path to be from the working directory, replace the os.walk() argument, os.getcwd() with '.'.

Comment: You can use `os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())` to get the relative path.

Comment: No worries, just to add in case, if you had multiple 'example.txt' files you were searching for I believe you would need to loop through files, e.g. `for file in files:` and then check if file is example.txt